# Is there a Typo in the effects of eX?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, medicine-and-drugs

eX is described as having an effect for "(8 – Body) hours, minimum of 1 hour", and then for the same time a disorienting backlash-effect. That much is clear. However, the backlash effects are two-part, and the second part is confusing me:

> When the effect wears off, the user suffers disorientation
> for a like period, **along with –2 to their Mental
> limit for (Body) hours**. <sup>1</sup>

Is the mentioning of the *full* body attribute here a typo and there is an errata on it or correct? No other drug or medicine hits you longer, the better your body is, and just in front of it it says *for a like period*, so the same *(8-body) hours* it. However, the German version in the Bodyshop <sup>2</sup> seems to be identical.

---

1 - Chrome Flesh p.180
2 - Bodyshop S.180

Comment: Catalyst isn't known for their errata unfortunately, I haven't seen anything on this issue (that doesn't mean there isn't any, or that there is no error however)

Comment: Pegasus is known to include unpublished errata, but they have this exactly the same in the german version... which... is odd...

Comment: There is *something* about Ex/Galak on the [german 5th edition pegasus forum... but... more than unauthoritative?](https://foren.pegasus.de/foren/topic/20773-sr5-allgemeine-kurze-fragen-kurze-antworten/?p=592213)

Comment: [official Chrome Flesh Errata](https://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?topic=24599.0) seem silent